# Import all Functions and Interfaces from Types Definition

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to invoke the following method in TypeScript:

```
nlp.text("Hi Dr. Miller the price is 4.59 for the U.C.L.A. Ph.Ds.").sentences.length
// 1
```

What would the correct import statement be to allow me to do this from this [types definition](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/compromise/blob/master/nlp.d.ts)?

Note that `text()` is the name of a function and of various methods in this definition. The former takes parameters, while the methods do not. I'm interested in the function.

I'm just not sure which symbol would give me the NLP function to defined in the js file [here](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/compromise/blob/master/builds/nlp_compromise.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as nlp from 'library'
// import { text } from 'library' - this would be much better

const length = nlp.text("...").sentences.length
// const length2 = text("...").sentences.length - using the second type of import
```

Obviously you'll have to replace `'library'` with the name of the package you import from.

If you would like to give the imported object a type, and use it somewhere, you could do something like this (it's not really a good idea though to keep type definitions in 2 places):

```
interface Nlp {
  text(string: string, options?: any): Text
  sentence(string: string): Sentence
  // ...
}

function iTakeAnNlp(input: Nlp): void {
  // ...
}

iTakeAnNlp(nlp)
```

Comment: How might I create a class property of type `nlp`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? For doing what you described in the question this works perfectly.

Comment: That's a good question. I suppose I've grown accustomed to the pattern of creating such properties, then calling them within my class's methods. For example `someMethod() { let foo = this.nlp.text('String').sentences.length }`

Comment: So you would like to know the static type of `nlp`? I'm afraid you won't find that in the definition file, since it's the union type of all exported functions/constants.

Comment: Precisely. Is there a way to create a static type definition? Or is an inherent feature of the module itself? I suppose I need to do some research on the distinction between static types and union types here.

Comment: Unless there is a new typescript feature, which allows you to alias the type of a value, I don't think it's possible. But since this library exposes "static" functions, why don't you just import what you need? like `import {text, otherStuff} from 'library'`? Much easier for the reader as well.

Comment: @J.AdamConnor Updated the answer, I think this is the best you can do...